# Fetching specific date from MySQL in FastAPI

Tags: python, mysql, fastapi

I want to fetch a date from mysql workbench according to a certain id (msisdn). But I don't know how to do it with SQLAlchemy. msisdn is the primary key.

Should emulate this query:

```
SELECT 
    last_port 
FROM 
    `realtime-backend`.portabilidad 
WHERE 
    last_port='2020-04-23 6:00:00' AND 
     msisdn='56977095634'
```

Models:

```
class PortabilidadInfo(Base):
      __tablename__ = "portabilidad"
      msisdn = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
      operator_id = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
      last_port = Column(Date, default=datetime.now(), nullable=True)
```

Code:

```
portabilidad_msisdn = '56977095634'
fecha_csv = '2020-04-23 6:00:00'
                
date_info = session.query(PortabilidadInfo).filter(PortabilidadInfo.last_port == fecha_csv).get(portabilidad_msisdn) 
print("FECHA BDD OBJ: ", date_info, type(date_info))
```

But I get an error saying this: `Query.get() being called on a Query with existing criterion.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine terms to the `filter` statement:

```
date_info = session.query(PortabilidadInfo).filter(
    PortabilidadInfo.last_port == fecha_csv,
    PortabilidadInfo.msisdn == portabilidad_msisdn,
).first()
```

This will retrieve the first row that matches both `last_port` and `portabilidad_msisdn`.

You can then access the value of `last_port` through `date_info.last_port`. However, since you're also including this value in your query, you can just check if a row was returned at all (so check if `date_info is None`, otherwise use `fecha_csv`).

`get` is a special construct to retrieve something from the `primary_key` field, and can't be applied together with other fields.

However, since `msisdn` is a primary key, there can't be any duplicates for that field, so this will only be able to retrieve a single row in either case (it will just return `None` if the date doesn't match).

Comment: How can access the value with date_info.last_port?. it gives me an error of 'str' object has no attribute 'last_port'.

Comment: Then it sounds like you've already changed what `date_info` is in some way; how you've done that is hard to say for anyone else. But if it has the value you're looking for now, then go ahead and use that (i.e. print out the value of `date_info` and see what you're trying to read a property on).